# Probability measure on $\Omega$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

> Let $\Omega := \mathbb{N}$ and $\mathcal{A} := \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$,
>   $p \in (0,1]$.
>
> Show that $\mathbb{P}(\{k\}) := (1-p)^kp$ $(k \in \mathbb{N}_0$)
>   defines a probability measure on $\Omega$.

My idea:

We know that $\Omega$ is an at most countable sample space and it is given that $\mathcal{A} := \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$.

Let $(p_w)_{w \in \Omega}$ be probability mass function. Then $\mathbb{P}(A) := \sum_{w \in A} p_w$. Let $\mathbb{P}$ be a probability measure on $\Omega$. Then $p_w := \mathbb{P}(\{w\})$.

Now, we have $p_w := (1-p)^wp$ $(w \in \mathbb{N_0})$ and $\mathbb{P}(A) := \sum_{w \in A} (1-p)^w p$.

And now I should prove that the conditions are fullfiled?

> $(a)$ $\mathbb{P}(\emptyset) = 0$, $\mathbb{P}(\Omega) = 1$.
>
> $(b)$ If $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathcal{A}$ such that $(A_n)$
>   is pairwise disjoint then $\mathbb{P}\,(\bigcup _{n \in \mathbb{N}}{A_ n}) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{P}(A_n)$.

Is this Ansatz correct?

Comment: you only need to sum them up to 1.

Comment: It's not written, but we mean that $P(A) = \sum_{k\in A} P(\{k\})$ so countable additivity is achieved trivially, and like Benjamin says, all left to do is compute $P(N)$. That is, we are asking if $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (1-p)^kp = 1$.

Comment: @Jakobian Ah, I understand. So I only have to show that $\mathbb{P}(\Omega)$ sums up to $1$ and is thus a probability measure on $\Omega$?

Now, we can see that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (1-p)^kp$ is a geometric series where $p \in (0,1]$, so we get $\frac {p}{1-(1-p)} = \frac {p}{p} = 1$?

Comment: @TestoTesta Correct. More generally it can be proved for every countable set $\Omega$ that there is a one-to-one correspondence between functions $f:\Omega\to[0,\infty)$ that satisfy $\sum_{\omega\in\Omega}f(\omega)=1$ and probability measures on measurable space $(\Omega,\wp(\Omega))$.